# AWS EC2, NodeJS - cannot find module

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have NodeJS successfully installed and running on AWS EC2. I use script for automatically start it. It also works fine.
Now I want to install another instance of the same application - under separate folder and listens on different port.
After the second install I have got two separate node projects:
- `/var/nodes/fc-dev` - dev node and
- `/var/nodes/fc-prod` - production node
I also create separate script for production module - `/etc/init/fc-prod.conf`
Here is `/etc/init/fc-dev.conf` script:
    # Saves log to /var/log/upstart/fc-dev.log
    console log

```
# Starts only after drives are mounted.
start on started mountall

stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn. But fail permanently if it respawns 10 times in 5 seconds:
respawn
respawn limit 10 5

script
   exec sudo NODE_ENV=development /usr/bin/node --debug /var/nodes/fc-dev/fc-server.js
end script
```

and here is the `/etc/init/fc-prod.conf`file:

```
# Saves log to /var/log/upstart/fc-dev.log
console log

# Starts only after drives are mounted.
start on started mountall

stop on shutdown

# Automatically Respawn. But fail permanently if it respawns 10 times in 5 seconds:
respawn
respawn limit 10 5

script
   exec sudo NODE_ENV=production /usr/bin/node /var/nodes/fc-prod/fc-server.js
end script
```

I successfully start dev project by `sudo start fc-dev`, however when I type `sudo start fc-prod`, I have got following error:

```
module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
'rror: Cannot find module '/var/nodes/fc-prod/fc-server.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
```

On the other hand, typing `sudo NODE_ENV=production /usr/bin/node /var/nodes/fc-prod/fc-server.js` allows me to start production node.
What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After additional attempts and fails I solved the issue as follow:
`sudo cp fc-dev.conf fc-prod.cp`
`sudo nano fc-prod.conf` - and edit the file removing debug related parameter and changing destination folder to production one. I also compared both file versions of production config files and the only differences I have got were some special chars - `LFCR` and `LF`
Hope this helps somebody in the future.